# In the entries listing (backend), how can I disable the preview button in Craft 3?

Tags: entries

I'm building a single page site, so there wont be a page for each entry. How can I disable the preview (world) button for each entry? I'm using the structure section type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to leave the **Entry URI Format** field in the section settings blank. That will disable the "world icon" in the entry index as well as the Live Preview and Share buttons on the individual entry edit pages, as well as several other things (for example, there will be no `{{ entry.url }}` available in the templates).

[image]